# Updating ConnectionPool in Glassfish when derby is upgraded

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, derby

I was using Glassfish4 with Eclipse and `derby-10.6` with `JEE`. Everything was working fine. Then for some tutorials I switched to `Netbeans8.1` which had `Glassfish4.1.1` and `derby-10.12`. Now I am back to `Eclipse` and want to start from where I left. Meanwhile database created by derby-10.6 is upgraded by 10.12. How can I change settings in `Glassfish4` so that it can connect to the database? I am guessing I need to change something with `ConnectionPool`.

The error I am getting is:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [ejb] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 0, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Failed to start database 'EmployeeDB' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@61bbe9ba, see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XSLANDatabase at C:...\db-derby-10.6.2.1-bin\bin\EmployeeDB has an incompatible format with the current version of the software. The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.9. Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.

Note that, I don't have derby-10.9.

Comment: It should not be more complicated than changing the CLASSPATH settings in your Eclipse configuration to point to your Derby 10.12 jars instead of your Derby 10.6 jars. I suspect the message about 10.9 is just because 10.9 is when that particular incompatibility was introduced.